# WPF BusyWindow unbreakable by main thread

Tags: wpf, multithreading, user-interface, window

How to create really unbreakable wpf busy window in separate thread?
Main thread run some a few second lasting intensive computation code. This code can not allow call UI refresh (DoEvents)(do not have cycle), and is not moveable to separate thread.

Busy Window have some spinner/progress, which should rotate/move. But it doesn't rotate/move if the main thread run intensive computation.

Most of "busy window in separate thread" - founded on web - do not work, if the main thread run intensive computation (nor Task, nor BackgroundWorker). Limitation is .net framework 4.0.

For testing, if I try to run intensive code in the main thread:

```
while(true) {}
```

then most web "busy window in separate thread" became blocked.

Best results I have with this code:

```
 var thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
        {
            SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(
                new DispatcherSynchronizationContext(
                    Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher));

            asyncCtl = creator();
            asyncCtl.CreateControl();
            asyncCtl.Show();

            System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
        }));


        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.IsBackground = true;
        thread.Start();

        Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.ShutdownStarted += CurrentDispatcher_ShutdownStarted;
        Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.ShutdownFinished += CurrentDispatcher_ShutdownFinished;
```

When computation function finished, this code is called:

```
  asyncCtl.Dispatcher.BeginInvokeShutdown(DispatcherPriority.Background);
```

But - events  ShutdownStarted  / ShutdownFinished are called on main thread exits. This seems to me too late.
If application run BusyWindow 10 times, these events are called 10 times on main thread exits.
I afraid if there are 10 times shown BusyWindow, there stay hang 10 non-shutdowned threads which ends lately -  on main application exits.

So, how to correctly create and dispose such busy window? 
Thanks.

Comment: Programmers too often get this backwards.  Display the "busy window" on the UI thread, run the expensive code on a worker.  A standard .NET class like BackgroundWorker gets usable, you can't get the RunworkerCompleted event wrong like you did for ShutdownStarted.

Comment: If there is a ten thousands lines of old complicated code, there is not possible to redesign it to work in BackgrounWorker. The question was, how to correctly display busy window in separate thread (without calling DoEvents - is not possible). Thanks.